# Initialisation of custom Shoula macros

Tags: ruby-on-rails, shoulda

I've written a custom Shoulda macro and placed it under *test/shoulda_macros* directory.  What else should I do in order to use my custom macro in my test case file? Should I reopen TestCase class? Anything else? I am probably missing something simple. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In shoulda 3.x, the term went from "macros," to "matchers." You can see exactly how the [shoulda-matchers](https://github.com/thoughtbot/shoulda-matchers) gem works with TestUnit [here](https://github.com/thoughtbot/shoulda-matchers/blob/master/lib/shoulda/matchers/integrations/test_unit.rb).

You can either extract your matchers into a new gem and perhaps publish the gem if it's general enough to be of use to others. Otherwise, you can extend TestCase in your test_helper.rb file, or put that code in it's own file and require it from test_helper. Something like this:

```
require 'lib/shoulda-matchers-custom'

module Test
  module Unit
    class TestCase
      include Shoulda::Matchers::Custom
      extend Shoulda::Matchers::Custom
    end
  end
end
```